# How to wire up event with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

See below sample.  I need to wire up the DoSomething method obtained though reflection to an event.

```
    class Program {
    private static event EventHandler MyEvent;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object aType = new SomeType();

        var type = aType.GetType();

        var method = type.GetMethod("DoSomething");

        if (method != null)
        {
            MyEvent += method;//How do I wire this up?
        }
    }
}


public class SomeType {
    public void DoSomething() {
        Debug.WriteLine("DoSomething ran.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a delegate:

```
MyEvent += (EventHandler)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventHandler), aType, method);
```

The second argument is the instance to bind the delegate to.
For more information, see [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/open-delegates-vs-closed-delegates.html/).

Like any other delegate, this will only work if the target method has the same signature (parameter types) as the delegate.

Comment: You also need to cast the result of CreateDelegate to EventHandler

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  This was very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you can't use `DoSomething` as a handler for `MyEvent`, because it doesn't have the right signature. Assuming you change the signature of `DoSomething` to this:

```
public void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

You can subscribe to the event like this:

```
    if (method != null)
    {
        var dlg = (EventHandler)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventHandler), aType, method);
        MyEvent += dlg;
    }
```